# OPCUA Server doesn't receive host/port/sock to start

Tags: python, server, opc-ua

During a small test to learn how to run a small server, the method 'start' returns an error when I tried to start the server afet including the endpoint and some variables:

```
from opcua import Server
import datetime
import time


my_server = Server()
url = 'opc.tcp//192.168.1.5:4841'
my_server.set_endpoint(url)
name = "OPCUA_TEST_Server"
addspace = my_server.register_namespace(name)
node = my_server.get_objects_node()

param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")

t_text1 = param.add_variable(addspace, "Text 1", "Text_1")
i_int1 = param.add_variable(addspace, "myInteger1", 0)
b_bool1 = param.add_variable(addspace, "myBool1", False)

t_text1.set_writable()
i_int1.set_writable()
b_bool1.set_writable()

my_server.start()
print("Server started at {}".format(url))
print("At" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

while True:




    time.sleep(0.5)
```

And in line of

```
my_server.start()
```

Returns the following error:

```
Endpoints other than open requested but private key and certificate are not set.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a767611/Desktop/Repositorios/flexigrid/opc-ua-server/test-opc-ua-server.py", line 23, in <module>
    my_server.start()
  File "C:\Users\a767611\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\server.py", line 347, in start
    raise exp
  File "C:\Users\a767611\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\server.py", line 344, in start
    self.bserver.start()
  File "C:\Users\a767611\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\server\binary_server_asyncio.py", line 116, in start
    self._server = self.loop.run_coro_and_wait(coro)
  File "C:\Users\a767611\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\common\utils.py", line 197, in run_coro_and_wait
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Users\a767611\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1393, in create_server
    raise ValueError('Neither host/port nor sock were specified')
ValueError: Neither host/port nor sock were specified
```

Comment: Maybe read.. `url = 'opc.tcp//192.168.1.5:4841'` -> `url = 'opc.tcp://192.168.1.5:4841'` btw. to spin up locally use `url = 'opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4841'` and if you don't give certificates, set `my_server.set_security_policy([ua.SecurityPolicyType.NoSecurity])`. Use the examples in [Repos](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/master/examples/server-example.py)

Answer (score 2):

Your endpoint URL is malformed.

It should be:

```py
url = 'opc.tcp://192.168.1.5:4841'
```

note the missing colon after `opc.tcp`.